# how to filter a getter in doctrine2 entity?

Tags: php, filter, doctrine, doctrine-orm, getter

I have an entity that has a one-to-many association (many-to-many with extra fields):

```
class Game {
    /**
    /* @OneToMany(targetEntity="GamePlayer", mappedBy="game", cascade={"persist"})
    /* @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="game_id", onDelete="cascade")
     */
    private $gamePlayer;
}
```

The class has automated getter for all the authors: getGamePlayers()

I would like to add a filter to it, so it would query the database only for the relevant details in the most efficient way:

```
public function getGamePlayersWithScoreHigherThan($score){
    //what to write here? (return array)
}
```

What is the best way to achieve such a getter from within the entity (not using the repository)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: How is the getter generated? What keeps you from adding your own custom getter to the entity?

Comment: it is generated from cli- php doctrine.php orm:generate-entities.
i can add the getter but i have no idea what to write inside in order to change the query.

Comment: Please post the complete entity

Comment: Why do you not want to use a repository? That is the recommended way to achieve this.

Comment: Dirk- it's not a real entity, i'm just simulating a similar problem i have at work.

Comment: Squazic- because in the view there's access to the $game and i want to do this: $game->getGamePlayersWithScoreHigherThan(10); i don't want to add this function to the controller and then pass it as another variable to the view.

Comment: What is it if it's not an entity?

Comment: It is an entity. what i've meant is that i can't copy it here because i've made it up.

Comment: no one? i didn't think it's that complicated - how to filter associations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try creating a separate method on your entity that uses the `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria` to filter the associated collection. See [this link](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) for details.